# font-size: min(3.58vw, 16px) !important; is not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

with bootstrap
I try to use

```
label {
font-size: min(3.58vw, 16px) !important;
}
```

but it is not working while

```
label {
 font-size: 3.58vw 
}
```

is working

### EDIT

That's the maximum I can put

```
<div  class="parent">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck6" (click)="displayAllInformation();" formControlName="RAS">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck6">Voulez vous avoir des simulations avec des crédits d'impôts.</label>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code as well so others can reproduce the problem

Comment: Certainly seems to be working in a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/trw530q1/1/ If you could post more code so we can see what's going on that'd be great.

Comment: Thank you, I added it as EDIT

Comment: I just did it with your exact code and it is still working: https://jsfiddle.net/trw530q1/2/  What are you expecting the text to do? what does "not working" mean?

Comment: I mean that when the window width is small (under which 3.58vw is less than 16px) the font size should be 3.58vw

Comment: So you want your text to always be 16px unitl the screen gets small then it will start to shrink to 3.58vw correct?  Because that is exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Correct, I can see it in firebug but it is crossed. When I remove all other font-size in firebug, it is still crossed

Comment: You might be declaring the min font size somewhere else with an important tag.  If you're sure that is not it then I don't think I can help as I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: label {
  font-size: 12px; 
}  works  while    label {
  font-size: min(12px, 16px) !important;. does not work. So it is due to min function
}

Comment: Is your site live? Can you send a like to it if it is? Maybe I can see something because I don't have an answer for you with your provided information.

Comment: sorry, but the site is not live, it is under development. This issue is strange

Comment: I will come back tomorrow to see if it is still not working

Comment: It is working with Safari. So it is due to Firefox. I will come back tomorrow to see if it is still not working with Firefox. The post is CLOSED. Sorry for the inconvenience